# Xcode Dependency Analysis Error

Tags: ios, xcode, dependencies

Does anyone know why I am getting these code signing errors?

For error one, I **do not** have 'In-app purchases' turned on in the project dependancies.

[image]

I am trying to run my project on my iPhone but I keep getting these three errors. My project ran perfectly on my iPhone yesterday but today I get the above errors.

Some possible solutions I have tried:

- Updating Xcode
- Restarting Xcode to factory defaults using Terminal
- Removing and adding my Apple ID back to Xcode
- Factory resetting my MacBook and reinstalling Xcode
- Deleting Xcode from my MacBook and reinstalling

If any addition information is required to improve this question please feel free to ask. Hope someone can help!

Comment: Note: this could be a problem with having a non paid Apple developer account. I have recently put a paid account and it has solved the problem :)